# A good way to go from Dresden to Warsaw?

Tags: trains, germany, poland, warsaw

I will start the journey in the middle of Nov.

I do not want to fly.

Is there any good way, i mean, cheap and convenient, to go from Dresden to Warsaw? I do not drive.

I hear that it is cheaper to break the trip into a german part and a polish part?

Comment: Drive? Train? Crawl? Walk? Hitchhike?

Comment: i do not drive. bus or train.

Comment: @kaiser What do you mean with 'cheap and convenient'. In most travelling situations you can have something either cheap or convenient, but rarely both.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked [the German railway site](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en?ld=150103&seqnr=2&ident=1z.04466103.1443553485&rt=1&newrequest=yes&HWAI=~QUERY;~JS;~CONNECTION;~GLOBALAPPLICATION;&) and found several options for under €40 on 11-11-2015. I think that with that kind of prices it is not worth breaking the ticket unless you want to break the travel.

If you want to buy a ticket all in Poland, I think [this is the site to use.](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/en) But there might be other/better options, I never used the site.

Comment: DB site says "saver fare" with < EUR40 prizes, standard fare is 80 eur

Comment: You need to book early for the cheap fare, but if you are flexible there are often cheaper fares nearer the day.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.euroticket.pl/en/index.php

here you can find bus tickets, it takes around 9 hrs of travel and costs around 50-60 EUR

Comment: http://eurobus-eurolines.pl/en/ and here, a bit more expensive, but the carrier is well-known in Poland, maybe better buses, more reliable in general

Comment: Why is the bus so expensive? In Germany, it is much cheaper. From dresden to berlin, 2:30h, 7 EUR

Comment: routes within Poland are also much cheaper, but here we're talking about going abroad

Comment: if price is more important than time or easiness, then you can actually try to go to the border (in Goerlitz), cross it and go from Zgorzolec to Warsaw by bus or train, it will be much cheaper, but definitely longer and there is no direct connection so you would have to change trains/buses in Zielona Gora... or similarly through Frankfurt am Oder / Slubice border pass